# How to output Command prompt to a log file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm not a programmer so I don't want to overly irritate the fine folk in this forum.  My issue is that I would like to use VBScript to Telnet into a Linux device, issue a **DF** command and output all response to a log file which I can parse later. I originally found a method to successfully Telnet but I have have been experimenting without success regarding the text file output requirement.  The following code certainly does not work but I am wondering if I am even close to the correct method?

```
Dim WshShell, oExec  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c dir")

WshShell.run"cmd" '*** open command window ***  
WScript.Sleep 250  

WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WshShell.SendKeys"telnet 10.13.2.2"  
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WScript.Sleep 2000  

WshShell.SendKeys"root"  
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WScript.Sleep 1500  

WshShell.SendKeys"password"  
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WScript.Sleep 1500  

Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\VBSmemSize.txt", 2, True)  

WshShell.SendKeys"df /mnt/cf"  
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
Do  
  strFromProc = oExec.Stdout.Readline()  
  WScript.Echo strFromProc  
Loop While Not objLogFile.StdOut.atEndOfStream
```

Comment: You may have better success batching with `ssh` than `telnet`. If you've not set this up, I warn you that it's no trivial, but totally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture output from external commands but not at the same time interact with them like you do with sendkeys. Here an example of what works

```
Function ExecPing(strTarget)
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objExec = objShell.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & strTarget)
  strPingResults = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
  If InStr(strPingResults, "antwoord van") Then '"reply from" in E
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & strTarget & " responded to ping."
    ExecPing = True
  Else
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & strTarget & " did not respond to ping."
    ExecPing = False
  End If
End Function

ExecPing pcname
```